# "\x9D" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, unidecoder

I have created a csv uploader on my rails app, but sometimes I get an error of

> "\x9D" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8

This is the source to my uploader:

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding: "windows-1252:utf-8") do |row|
    title = row[1]
    row[1] = title.to_ascii
    description = row[2]
    row[2] = description.to_ascii
    Event.create! row.to_hash
  end
end
```

I am using the unidecode gem (https://github.com/norman/unidecoder) to normalize any goofy characters that a user may input. I've ran into this error a few times, but can't determine how to fix it. I thought the `encoding: "windows-1252:utf-8"` line would fix the problem, but nothing there.

Thanks stack!

Answer (score 2):

There is no 9D character (as well as 81, 8D, 8F, 90) in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). It means your text is *not* in Windows-1252 encoding. At the very least your source text is corrupt.

Comment: Hmm, okay. So removing the `encoding: "windows-1251:utf-8"` and trying the upload again just caused a `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error. Sorry, I'm in my early stages of developing hah.

Comment: @Devan The source charset might be [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250), which is used for Central European and Easter European Latin script languages and has character 9D.

Comment: I'll give it a test. 

Is there a way to the CSV uploader to allow all encodings? I have a gem that is normalizing the strings in the encoder, so it doesn't matter if it allows only a specific encoding type though.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this error from reading url contents:

```
table = CSV.parse(URI.open(document.url).read)
```

Turns out the API I am fetching conditionally returns *GZIP* if the file is too large.

Another annoying thing is that rails decompression was then failing on a valid UTF8 error.

This did NOT work:

```
ActiveSupport::Gzip.decompress(URI.open(document.url).read)
```

This did work:

```
Zlib::GzipReader.wrap(URI.open(document.url), &:read)
```

My next problem is the `CSV.parse()` reads the entire blob, and I had a single line with errors.

```
downloaded_file = StringIO.new(Zlib::GzipReader.wrap(URI.open(document.url), &:read))
tempfile = Tempfile.new("open-uri", binmode: true)
IO.copy_stream(downloaded_file, tempfile.path)
headers = nil
File.foreach(tempfile.path) do |line|
  row = []
  if headers.blank?
    headers = CSV.parse_line(line, { col_sep: "\t", liberal_parsing: true })
  else
    line_data = CSV.parse_line(line.force_encoding("UTF-8").encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace), { col_sep: "\t", liberal_parsing: true })
    row = headers.zip(line_data)
  end
  puts row.inspect
  ... # do a lot more stuff
end
```

wow.